# Error when connecting to Redshift with JDBC41/4

Tags: amazon-web-services, pentaho, amazon-redshift, kettle, pdi

I am trying to connect to Redshift from Pentaho Kettle with JDBC

I have downloaded the JDBC41 jar(https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.10.1010.jar) from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html

and put it into kettle/lib, set connection string correctly so that static check of connection passed showing

```
Connection to database [redshift_xx] is OK.
Custom URL : jdbc:redshift://redshift-xx:5439/dbname
Custom Driver Class:com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver
```

but get a runtime error

```
com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.directExecute(Ljava/lang/String;ILcom/amazon/support/IWarningListener;)Ljava/util/List;
```

the same with jdbc4

Comment: I am faced with similar issue with the Redshift 4.1 driver. However, on Pentaho's site it states to only use the version 4 driver. I still could not connect. Have you found a solution yet?